# Duplicate content-disposition headers with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, browser, download

Im trying  to open pdf files or other files types like images with the browser but ff and chrome are giving the duplicate content error. I am using the code below to open the files.

```
Response.Contentype = file.ContentType;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",string.Format("inline;filename=\"{0}\"",file.Filename));
return File(file.Data,file.ContentType,file.FileName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the first 2 lines of your code. They are not needed. The `return File(file.Data, file.ContentType, file.FileName);` method already already adds a `ContentType` (because of the second argument) and `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment` (because of the third argument).

If you don't want set the Content-Disposition header to attachment but `inline` then remove the third argument:

```
return File(file.Data, file.ContentType);
```

Comment: If I do that, it prompts for a download. the code above works for ie9

Comment: Yes it prompts for a download because when you specify a third argument, the Content-Disposition header is set to `attachment` which is normal. If you want to display the file `inline` you should omit the third argument.

Comment: Just out of interest, how do I open it in a new tab.

Comment: This could only be done on the client, not on the server. For example if you have a link to this controller action simply add the `target="_blank"` attribute to this anchor. This could also be done with CSS3 for browsers that support it. Take a look at the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/

Comment: This is great. However, the issue I have is that, in this case, the browser will download a file without extension and, therefore, still not open it in browser. Any ideas?